# How to update listFragment on Master Detail Flow Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm using Master Detail Flow Activity and I have a `ListFragment` and `DetailFragment`, on both `Fragments` I have an instance of `SQLiteHelper` a helped made by me to do actions to my `SQLite`.

My question is on my `DetailFragment` I have a `Button` that can delete an item (I have the id of my product so I can simply remove it), but my question is, as I'm using `Master detail flow` when I remove the product from `DetailFragment` I have to do something like `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` or something like that but my adapter and all of the stuff of my `RecyclerView`, how do I get reference from my `DetailFragment` to the `Adapter` from my `ListFragment`?

### Note: on my `MainActivity` I do not have anything but the creation of `Fragment`

My questions are :

1. On my `MainActivity` I do not have anything but the creation of the `Fragment`, well my `MainActivity` implements an `Interface` that is being called from `Adapter` to replace the current `Fragment`, is that ok?
2. On both `Fragment`s I have a `newInstance()` of my `SQLiteHelper`, could I put it on my `Activity` so I can use the same object?
3. The problem is that I need to update the `RecyclerView` from my `DetailFragment` and on it I do not have anything about `RecyclerView`, so I can not do something like `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` or something like that, I only can remove the current item, how can I connect my `DetailFragment` to refresh the `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 0):

> On my MainActivity I do not have anything but the creation of the Fragment, well my MainActivity implements an Interface that is being called from Adapter to replace the current Fragment, is that ok?

Sure, but you will want to also keep a reference to the master fragments at least to delegate the delete action to it in response to the action in the detail fragment.

> On both Fragments I have a newInstance() of my SQLiteHelper, could I put it on my Activity so I can use the same object?

Sure. Usually you have the SQLite access object be a singleton of some sort. Accessing it through the one Activity is one way of doing that.

> The problem is that I need to update the RecyclerView from my DetailFragment and on it I do not have anything about RecyclerView, so I can not do something like adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() or something like that, I only can remove the current item, how can I connect my DetailFragment to refresh the RecyclerView?

Please check the official docs on [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating).

You can adapt the strategy for your use case by having an `OnDeleteListener` that the `DetailFragment` invokes with the index or ID of the item that is being deleted. Then the Activity would delegate to the `MasterFragment` to let it know the item was deleted so it could call [notifyItemRemoved](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRemoved(int)) on its adapter.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you make a simple exampel of onDelete Listener pelase?

Comment: Also my problem is that I have the adapter and recyclerview on my listFragment I have to implements that interface on my ListFragment to do the stuff?

Comment: Why don't you post some code of what you have done so far and I can make some suggestions from there.